# Assistance combining two if statements

Tags: excel, formula

I need to combine two if statements together in one cell, i have so far come up with the following,

=IF(ISBLANK(F2),"",F2-D2)
=IF(ISBLANK(G2),"",G2-D2)

I need both of these to be in the one cell, F2 is a manual entry cell, and G2 is automated with a formula of =IF(E2="No",D2+"0:10","") where this formula will look in E2 if it finds no then it will add 10 mins on to the time in D2.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mmm, can you clarify what's the ultimate goal of the combined statement? Maybe an example?
Do you want an if/else if/else? Then you can just nest the 2 statements like this: IF(ISBLANK(F2),IF(ISBLANK(G2),"",G2-D2),F2-D2)

Comment: Please update your question with some sample data and your expected output. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

By combining, I assume you mean concatenating? Therefore you can use the `&` operator, something like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F2),"",F2-D2) & ";" & IF(ISBLANK(G2),"",G2-D2)
```

(I'm using semicolon as a separator.)